# Backup Solution for windows and ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, backup

Are there any solutions out there that will backup all windows and ubuntu machines on my home network?

This needs to happen nightly.

I am looking for something like Windows Home server(which currently works freat for windows only machines), however, i have ubuntu machines in my house as well.

I also do not want to have seperate tools for each os, but rather one magic little app that handles most

Answer (score 1):

http://www.amanda.org/ try this

Answer (score 1):

I'm very happy with Bacula:

[Bacula, the Open Source, Enterprise ready, Network Backup Tool for Linux, Unix, and Windows](http://www.bacula.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

[BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) is the perfect fit for this. It is in the Ubuntu repositories which makes it very easy to install and set up.

You create shares on the Windows PCs that you want backed up, and you can either run Samba to create shares on the Ubuntu PCs or use rysnc to backup the Ubuntu PCs.

I use it in the same scenario and it has a really nice Web Interface that is easy to use and makes restoring files very easy too.

The bonus for me was that the backups are stored as files on disk and not in a database. This gives me an extra level of assurance as I can easily restore files even without having BackupPC running.

Another awesome feature is the way it uses disk pooling to use impossibly small amounts of disk space compared to what it is backing up.

Check out the [features on the website](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/info.html).